# XSLT - Add some spacing before punctuation

Tags: xslt, saxon, apache-fop

I use Apache FOP version 2.8 with saxonHE12 available.

Is there a way in XSLT to add an additional space BEFORE the punctuation character when punctuating (, ? ! etc)?

I have seen that there is something from Antennahouse [axf:space-before-punctuation](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/antenna-house/elements/space-before-punctuation) but as far as I know I can't use it as FOP user.

Is there any other way to add, for example, an extra space of say 0.2 cm before each comma?

Example:

```
The sun was setting, casting a warm golden glow over the horizon.
```

Output after adding some spacing:

```
The sun was setting<spacing of 0.2 cm>, casting a warm golden glow over the horizon<spacing of 0.2 cm>.
```

Comment: Without an example input/output it's difficult to understand what the problem is. Please edit your question for adding a sample input+output that illustrates the problem

Comment: I want this feature: [axf:space-before-punctuation](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/antenna-house/elements/space-before-punctuation) but without using Antennahouse Formatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your output format is HTML, you can enclose the punctuation characters in `span` elements and style them with CSS:

```xml
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[,.!?]">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <span style="padding-left:2px"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

<sup>**remark:** It's my first time making use of `xsl:analyze-string`</sup>

The output would be something like:

```xml
The sun was setting<span style="padding-left:2px">,</span> casting a warm golden glow over the horizon<span style="padding-left:2px">.</span>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was doing in a current 'workaround' solution. But i did it the dirty way with disable-output-escaping="yes" and `replace(text(), ',', '&lt;span class=&quot;punctuation-mark&quot;&gt;,&lt;/span&gt;')"`

Yours is definetly the better solution and i will build this into my script. Thank you :)

Comment: Seems like using the `analyze-string` **element** would be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Do you get the correct rendition if you add a thin-space character (U+2009) before the comma? If so, you could add that from XSLT by doing something like

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ',', '&#x2009;,')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hmm no, unfortuantely this adds too much space... Is there another option?

Comment: There's also the hair-space U+200A. Or try outputting it in a different font size?

Comment: That comes really close to the desired output...
I found out that i just need a space that takes no space... like the U+200A but even smaller.
Strangely enough, the box of the last letter is "reduced" when I comma...
I have uploaded an example to clarify what I mean here: https://imgur.com/a/Nxstetg
If the comma is directly at the last letter then the conatainer of the "r" suddenly does not close anymore with the rightmost edge of the "r

Comment: That sort of detail is going to depend very much on how the output is rendered, including font details, which you haven't told us anything about.

Comment: I create HTML output with a self written xslt stylesheet and Apache FOP. The font is ITCFranklinGothicStd-Book wich i have locally on my machine as TrueType font and wich i converted to base64 css font-face.
In HTML i create a `<span>` element with css styling to use the ITCFranklinGothicStd-Book font.

Comment: @CrazyEight the comma being "closer" to a preceding `r` is probably due to [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning).

Comment: @lfurini That's it !!! I have added `font-kerning: none;` to my css and the result is great!
Never heard of that before :P